# Pulling a translation from the localization file based on a DB value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 7
```

I have a table (model), with locations names (historical sites). The schema is pretty sample:

```
Table name: locations_names
columns:
    id (integer)
    locales_string this is a string (congress, senate, smithsonian, etc)
```

and in in config/locales/en.yml file, I have:

```
en:
  location_names:
    congress: "Congress"
    senate: "Senate"
    smithsonian: "Smithsoneian Museum"
```

How do I use this in my Views, to construct a selection list, for instance, that's properly localized?

Comment: Maybe you should check out Mobility https://github.com/shioyama/mobility . It allows  storing and retrieving translations as attributes on a class

Comment: @R.Sierra is right on the money. The simple Yaml backend to the I18n module is not really meant for this use - if you want to localize your data and not just your views you should be storing the localizations in the database unless you want to have to update your project code every time you add new data.